# Selenium Webdriver 2 with Firefox 26?

Tags: perl, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

This morning I was running Selenium with 2.32 and Firefox 25.0.1. Firefox updated to 26.0, and suddenly Selenium stopped working. It pops up the new browser window, but then just sits there prompting for a search or address. Is Selenium known to have a problem with this? Is it confused by the new prompt in the Firefox address bar? Has it already been fixed in a newer Selenium 2.3x?

While waiting for a fix, what is the easiest way to change my code to work with either Chrome or (yecch) IE10? I'd like to make my test code configurable so that others in my group can use their browser of choice (especially Chrome). I tried once to get Chrome to work by adding 'browser_name'=>'*chrome' to the new() method, but it never worked.

BTW, I am using the Perl language binding (Selenium::Remote::Driver 0.17).

Comment: You almost certainly need to be running the latest version of Selenium to have any chance, at all, of running with the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: I had same problem ... using Firefox v24 on Mac OSX running Java with selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar. When I upgraded to Firefox v26 it stopped working. I tried upgrading to 2.38.0 but the problem was still there. I downgraded Firefox back to v24 and everything started working again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try updating selenium to 2.38.0 (latest one at the time of writing).  I had something similar problem with firefox updating and then buttons not being clicked and upgrading the version solved it.  Hope this solves it.

Comment: OK, I was hoping to avoid updating yet again, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Have the same problem - update does not work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Update to selenium to 2.39.0 e.g:

```
<seleniumVersion>2.39.0</seleniumVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem after upgrading my selenium to 2.39.0. I couldn’t solve my problem so I switched to Chrome.

Download the Chrome driver and give it the path where you invoke the browser. Then it’s easy in Chrome:

```
if (config.getProperty("Browser").equals("chrome")) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the chromedriver");
    dri = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Comment: I tried some limited tests with 2.39.0 and Firefox, and had problems, so I'm back to 2.38.0.